# Where can I find a list of the default emoticons on Ice Cream Sandwich?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, keyboard

My fiance has figured out how to make android emoticons with hearts as eyes, and a kissing emoticon, and I'd like to send the same emoticons back to her, but I can't figure out how. Is there a list of the default emoticons in Ice Cream Sandwich and Jelly Bean?

*Edit*: To clarify, I'm looking to find a table showing how different strings of characters translate into the icons that ICS displays when I receive an emoticon.

Comment: Is this in the Messaging app?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are all the emoticons from Ice Cream Sandwich with typed string. And a couple of extra ones that are not mentioned above.

[image: Diagram of all ICS emoticons]

From http://juxtaposedgraphix.blogspot.in/2012/09/android-40-ics-emoticons-ice-cream.html

Answer (score 10):

I do not have a mapping between characters and images, but I was able to figure out where the images are stored and its contents.  The images are stored in  /system/framework/framework-res.apk.

Having pulled this file from ICS emulator, I extracted and found 16 files for emoticons grouped based on [DPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166677/android-screen-size-hdpi-ldpi-mdpi).

The following are the files and its preview for ldpi.
[image]

and the hdpi:
[image]

I could not find the map between the string that we type and its corresponding image.  There are many Google search results that will help to replace these image files and add some more stuff as well.  The added emoticons will make sense only if both sender and receiver has this modification, else it will be seen just as a text only.

I know this does not answer your question, but while trying to find out one I stumbled on this information which could be useful for some one or some one knowledgeable enough can take it from here.

## Mapping

[Roxan shows us that Android's default keyboard has 16 emotions when you long press the ":-)" key.](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/26542/440) Let's see if we can figure out how the map to the symbols:

```
:-)   emo_im_happy
:-(   emo_im_sad
:-D   emo_im_laughing
:'(   emo_im_cyring
:-/   emo_im_undecided
:-[   emo_im_embarrassed
O:-)  emo_im_angel
:-!   emo_im_foot_in_mouth
:-$   emo_im_money_mouth
B-)   emo_im_cool
:-*   emo_im_kissing
:O    emo_im_yelling
=-O   emo_im_suprised
:-P   emo_im_toungue_sticking_out
;-)   emo_im_winking
:-X   emo_im_lips_are_sealed
o.O   emo_im_wtf
```

<sup>You can edit the answer if you found an error or a new mapping</sup>

Answer (score 0):

While typing a message in default keyboard there is an emotion button in the right bottom corner. If you long press it, it will show you all the emotions.

[image: Screenshot]

Source:
http://androidspin.com/2011/11/20/ice-cream-sandwich-keyboard-available-for-download-and-install/

Comment: That shows me the characters used to create the emoticon. I'm looking to figure out how they translate into the icons that ICS displays when I receive one of these emoticons.

Comment: I don't know if I still understand you but its just direct mapping. For eg: characters that forms smiley face translates to smiley emotion, characters forming sad face translates to sad emotion and so on.

Comment: Type one of each into a text message, and Android will happily display the results for you.

Answer (score 0):

Select the menu butyon at bottom when keyboard is open..not on keyboard but menu button on phone..then insert smiley will be an option.  Select that and default all smiley "icons" will display.  There are more than the keybaod smile displays.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

On your phone go to the play store and look for emoji keyboards for galaxy, after you install it you should set everything up then it will show squares after it shows squares in the notification bar you should see something you need to download so that you can see the emojis download that and set it up and your emojis should show up.

There is currently no updates for the galaxy s2 all though i tryed to update it for colored emojis i will update you if i see any updates. 
(this is for ice cream sandwhich)